# Constructing lists in scheme

Tags: scheme

I would like to do the following:

Lets say we have a list of data (3 2 1 5 4)

I want to construct a new list by taking the first two elements of the list (car list) and (cadr list) and concatenating it with the rest of the list (cddr list).

During my testing, I've tried numerous ways to accomplish this and none of them have resulted in what I want. In the testing, the result I am looking for is (2 3 1 5 4).

Here are the things I have tried.

```
> (define b1 '( 3 2 1 5 4))
> b1

(3 2 1 5 4)

> (list (cadr b1) (car b1) (cddr b1))

(2 3 (1 5 4))  -- notice here that it becomes a list inside of a list.

> (cons (cadr b1) (cons (car b1) (cons (cddr b1) '())))

(2 3 (1 5 4)) -- notice here that it becomes a list inside of a list.

> (list (cons (cadr b1) (car b1)) (cddr b1))

((2 . 3) (1 5 4)) -- Something strange happens here, we get a period.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
> (append (list (cadr b1) (car b1)) (cddr b1))
(2 3 1 5 4)
```

Comment: It's all right, FatalProphet. But, please, don't be silly and learn the beautiful language properly, instead of just trying to pass the exam ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `list*` (in Racket):

```
(list* (cadr b1) (car b1) (cddr b1))
```

or `cons*` (in Scheme):

```
(import (rnrs))
(display (cons* (cadr b1) (car b1) (cddr b1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(cons (cadr b1) (cons (car b1) (cddr b1)))
```

Remember is list is a pair whose cdr is a list or the empty list.